# Where was Alastor Moody in Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, it was mentioned that Moody attended Dumbledore's funeral.  Did Moody take part in the Battle of the lightning struck tower?  There seems to be no mentioning of Moody during this battle.  Can someone explain?  Thanks.

Comment: It appears that you already asked this question, so I [closed it as a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: @Alex meh... i would call them different *Where was he during the fight* and *Where was he during the entire book* seem different enough

Comment: @Niffler The title here mentions the book. Additionally, this would still be a subset of that question.

Answer (score 0):

## Unclear.

We do know that not everybody at the funeral took part in the battle, some of them just came for Dumbledore.

> An extraordinary assortment of people had already settled into half of the chairs: shabby and
>   smart, old and young. Most Harry did not recognise, but there were a few that he did, including
>   members of the Order of the Phoenix: Kingsley Shacklebolt, Mad-Eye Moody, Tonks, her hair
>   miraculously returned to vividest pink, Remus Lupin, with whom she seemed to be holding
>   hands, Mr. and Mrs. Weasley, Bill supported by Fleur and followed by Fred and George, who
>   were wearing jackets of black dragonskin. Then there was Madame Maxime, who took up twoand-a-half chairs on her own, Tom, the landlord of the Leaky Cauldron, Arabella Figg, Harry’s
>   Squib neighbour, the hairy bass player from the wizardmg group the Weird Sisters, Ernie Prang,
>   driver of the Knight Bus, Madam Malkin, of the robe shop in Diagon Alley, and some people
>   whom Harry merely knew by sight, such as the barman of the Hog’s Head and the witch who
>   pushed the trolley on the Hogwarts Express. The castle ghosts were there too, barely visible in
>   the bright sunlight, discernible only when they moved, shimmering insubstantially in the
>   gleaming air.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince, Chapter 30 (The White Tomb)</sub>

Seeing as "Most Harry didn't recognize" it's probable that they came from their homes for Dumbledore. Also, there are several characters that definitely weren't fit to fight i.e. Arabella Figg who was a Squib. As for Moody, he is never mentioned once during the Battle, so we can't be sure if he was there but it is possible he wasn't (and was otherwise employed). We also know that he wasn't positioned as a guard of Hogwarts at the beginning of the year.

> “But what are you doing here, anyway?” Harry asked.
>   “I’m stationed in Hogsmeade now, to give the school extra protection,” said Tonks.
>  
>   “Is it just you who’s stationed up here, or —?”
>   “No, Proudfoot, Savage, and Dawlish are here too.”
>   “Dawlish, that Auror Dumbledore attacked last year?”
>
> ---
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince, Chapter 8 (Snape Victorious)</sub>